# How can I dynamically activate submit button using javascript to send form data via POST?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a form that appends form data to bottom of the page when a button named verify is clicked (for users to review) and displays the submit button. The purpose of this submit button is to POST the form data to my php file.

I have tried to create the submit button like this below:

```
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "submit");
x.setAttribute("name", "submit");
x.setAttribute("id", "submitter");
var para= document.createElement("P");
para.appendChild(x);
```

I thought by including the script tags within form tags would allow me to still access form data, but when I look at source, it looks like the browser is processing the form closing tags before this submit button is created. So this submit button doesn't end up doing anything. My script tags currently are all the way at the bottom, so not sure if placement is the problem.

Alternatively I have tried to create a hidden submit button like below:

And then in my script to change the type to submit on button click:
    `document.getElementById('submitter').type ='submit';`

but this is giving me a cannot set propety type of 'null'.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you appending this button to a paragraph instead of the form?

Comment: You are right, this was an error on my part. I gave the form an Id, and created another variable    `var form2 = document.getElementById("form1");`   and now I am able to add the submit button to form by `form2.appendChild(x); ` now I am getting a different error, but it is coming from the php file. Thank you.

Comment: And? Did this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, all good. I have edited my response to add more detail.

Comment: If you open another question with your PHP code, I'd be glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the button to the page?

```
# append the content to your body or to any other element on the page
document.body.appendChild(para)?
```

#### Regarding post request:

> The purpose of this submit button is to POST the form data to my php file

Read about the [`jQuery.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and it should be very straightforward for you.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: You don't even need jQuery to POST the form data. Just use `document.forms[0].submit()`

Comment: Agree but using jQuery you can simplify it with `serialize` for example

Comment: yes, the button was added to the page. Regarding the post request: as a complete beginner to all things coding I am not familiar with jQuery at all. I was hoping to create this form at a very basic level and recreate it again an again as I learn more. I will read about jquery.post and try to implement in future revisions. Thank you for the suggestion.